# Is using redundant words (e.g. "7am in the morning") grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, redundancy

Is the use of redundant words grammatically correct? For example:

> I wake up at **7am in the morning**.
>
> I came here **as because** you are ill.

Comment: "I wake up at 7am in the morning" is correct. "I came here as because you are ill" is not correct. "At 7am" "in the morning" say related but different things. Use as many as you want: "I woke up early / first thing / at 7am / in the morning / as the sun was rising / on a new day."  On the other hand, "as because" is wrong. Both are conjunctions.

Comment: Who actually says that? I can semi-sorta kinda like understand why the first pleonasm might be used (it's akin to RAS syndrome, people tend not to think about what the abbreviation stands for), but I've never actually heard the second one – it sounds ungrammatical.

Comment: Cant I write as because fr double mentioning

Comment: @JeremyDouglass I've just noticed your comment: “a.m.” literally means “before noon” (which effectively translates to 0000–1200 military time), thus rendering “a.m.” and “in the morning” equivalent.

Comment: You don't use "buttered butter" speaking your mother tongue.What difference does it make?

Comment: It is true that "in the morning" doesn't provide additional information -- only emphasis. Strict repetition is unusual, however repeating closely related meanings for emphasis is quite common in English. "I'll see you, first thing, bright and early, in the morning!" -- all three of these phrases mean "in the morning." We often have no more problem with it than with someone saying they looked at the "falling rain" -- it doesn't bother us that all rain falls, nor do we think it implies that somewhere there is some rain that isn't falling.

Answer (score 2):

> I wake up at 7am in the morning.

This is grammatically correct but odd sounding, as it implies there's a 7am that doesn't exist in the morning.

> I came here as because you are ill.

This is not grammatically correct.  It looks like you are trying to join 2 clauses with 2 subordinating conjunctions and that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not grossly incorrect but is *quite* odd-sounding, as though it's being said for a humorous purpose, or because the speaker experienced a cognitive hiccup and got momentarily lost in the middle of the sentence.

[edited to clarify that I was only responding to the 7am part]

Comment: Which is grammatically correct? The first is, the second ("as because") certainly isn't.

Comment: I was only responding to the "7 am in the morning"

Comment: I'm probably more relaxed about redundancies, since they rarely impede understanding.  Strictly speaking, "7am in the morning" must be regarded as ungrammatical because there's only one slot for time, and "in the morning" is trying to crowd in when "7am" is already occupying the slot.